# acegi + facebook / myspace / google

Tags: facebook, spring-security, myspace

My app is using acegi as security.

Is there any facebook connect/google/myspace plugin I can hook up with acegi ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Grails ACEGI tutorial, specifically [this page](http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Customizing+with+SecurityConfig)

There are settings for OpenID, Facebook Connect, LDAP, NTLM, Kerberos, etc. right out of the proverbial box.

Comment: if i have spring application and i do not want to use grails. i cannot use the plugin u mentioned caused it involed grails right?   what i ant is facebook connect on spring security . can u comments

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that.  The ACEGI Grails plugin came from the base Spring Framework - specifically Spring Security.  See here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/  

I think the ACEGI has added onto the base functionality.  Grails is just Groovy code - so maybe you could back-port those features for facebook, etc.